# Is there a way to get an output with the "WITH" statement?

Tags: mysql, database

> Question: For all countries whose government form is a 'Federal Republic' and
>   whose official language is either 'English' or 'German', add 100,000
>   to their population, set their GNPOld to be equal to their current
>   GNP, then increase their current GNP by 10,000

[image: ERD]

So, I am given the above ERD as reference and while trying to answer the question I am wondering if I need to select the columns from the table before updating.

After some search on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html
I tried this

```
UPDATE country

SET Population = Population + 100000,
GNPOld = GNP,
GNP = GNP + 10000

WHERE GovernmentForm = 'Federal Republic' AND (Language = 'English' OR Language = 'German') AND IsOfficial = true;
```

***AND***

```
WITH GovernmentForm = 'Federal Republic' AND (Language = 'English' OR Language = 'German') AND IsOfficial = true

UPDATE country

SET ...
```

Both does not work. I am guessing the structure of my code to be wrong for this kind of query.
A pointer or a tip will be greatly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: There's no `Language` column in the `country` table. You need to join with `countryLanguage`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't think `city` is needed for this.

Comment: That's not what WITH does. Forget that WITH even exists, it doesn't help you solve your problem.

Comment: `true` is not a possible value of `isOfficial`. It's an ENUM, with the values `T` and `F`.

Comment: @Barmar - You are (as always) right. I thought population will need to be taken from there but country already has it.

Comment: Do I join before or after the {SET} ? Does {UPDATE} has to have the two tables mentioned ?

Comment: @PM77-1 I thought the same thing, but then wondered how we'd apportion the population increase among all the cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join with `countryLanguage` to get the `Language` and `IsOfficial` columns.

```
UPDATE country AS c
JOIN CountryLanguage AS cl ON c.Code = cl.CountryCode
SET c.Population = c.Population + 100000,
    c.GNPOld = c.GNP,
    c.GNP = c.GNP + 10000
WHERE c.GovernmentForm = 'Federal Republic' 
AND cl.Language IN ('English', 'German') 
AND cl.IsOfficial = 'T';
```

Also, `IsOfficial` is an ENUM, not a boolean. And I recommend using `IN()` to test for one of several possibilities, rather than `OR`.